# How to restrict role in magento to add products in one category

Tags: magento-1.7

Hi I have created a role named Retailer and I want the retailer to add products to one category named Books and not have the permission to access other than that and he has to access customers only from Books website..

Comment: Make sure to assign the permission to particular merchant, from admin panel.and also you can add a new role at system->permission->roles and add the Role Resources permission access to merchant.

Comment: But we cant restrict that particular merchant to access only particular category and products in that role resources permisssion

Answer (score 1):

There's number of commercial extension that allow you to set content specific permissions. By default Magento access control list only allows you to determine what modules you can access not what content objects you have permissions to read and update. Search for Magento Advanced Permissions to see what options are available.

Comment: I have searched advanced permissions in magento but all the extensions are paid versions only is there any other option??

Comment: No, this is rather complicated feature. You either pay for it or spend weeks to get build it yourself. I found that buying WAY cheaper (for example two hours of my work costs more to my customer than buying this extension).